# D3 shared zoom / transitions

Tags: d3.js

I'm hoping someone can shed insight on a D3 problem I'm having with a shared zoom and the use of a transition reset.

I have an app that contains multiple SVGs that I have all sharing a single zooming/panning behavior. That seems to work great.  But then I add a "reset" button with which I want to use D3's nice smooth transition function to return to the identity transform.  And that works, except...

If there's only one SVG listening to the zoom, works perfectly/smoothly
If there's two SVGs listening, the transition sporadically happens instantaneously rather than smoothly
If there's three or more SVGs listening, the transition seems to always happens instantaneously rather than smoothly

It seems like some sort of race condition, but I'm not sure if I've coded something wrong, or violated the usage rules of a shared zoom.

Below is code for a boiled down working demonstration of the behavior (you can enter different #s of SVGs to paint and then you can pan/zoom them together and then hit the reset button):
You can try this on codepen here: https://codepen.io/MatthewMJ/pen/ZEEEjPE

Thanks for any insights.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-random.v2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
How many rows?&nbsp;<input id="numrows"/><button onClick="repaint()">repaint</button>
<br><br>
<div id="block" display="block"></div>
<button onClick="reset()">reset zoom/pan</button>

<script>

    // One Zoom to Zoom them All
    var zoom = d3.zoom();

    // we'll have a user-specified # of SVGs of same size/layout defined here
    var dims = {
        width: 800,
        height: 50,
        svg_dx: 100,
        svg_dy: 25
    };

    // max value for made-up data
    var pointMax = 1000;

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, pointMax])
        .range([dims.svg_dx, dims.width - (dims.svg_dx * 2)]);


    function repaint() {
        d3.selectAll("svg").remove(); // clear out everything to start over
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("numrows").value; i++) {
            paint_one_row(i);
        }
    }

    function paint_one_row(i) {

        // generate 10 random points
        var data = d3.range(10).map(d3.randomInt(pointMax));

        // create the SVG into which we'll paint
        var svg = d3.select('#block')
            .append("div")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", dims.width)
            .attr("height", dims.height);

        // draw the circles
        var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('r', 7)
            .attr('cx', function (d) {
                return xScale(d);
            })
            .attr('cy', 10);

        // hook this SVG in with the central zoom
        svg.call(zoom);
        zoom.on('zoom.row' + i, zoomed.bind(svg));

        // each row should have it's own closure of 'zoomed' with differing 'circles'
        function zoomed() {
            var transform = d3.event.transform;

            // Zoom the circles
            var xNewScale = transform.rescaleX(xScale);
            circles
                .attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return xNewScale(d);
                });
        }
    }

    function reset() {
        d3.selectAll("svg").transition().duration(750).call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
    }

</script>
</body>
```